# What does "I'll make it" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

There's a song Paul Dano's character's singing in "Swiss Army Man" movie.

> Crazy, I'm freaking crazy, Maybe, just maybe
>   **I'll make it alone.** Rescued, Thought I was rescued, But you're just a dead dude and I'm gonna die. There's gotta be a better way to get out
>   of here

I can't understand what does "make it" mean in this context. General definition of "make it" is "to achieve one's goals". I can't understand what goal does the guy have.

Comment: To make it = to survive, or to succeed.

Comment: @TRomano I think OP will need more help than that because the next line on is "I'm gonna die"! So maybe it means something more like "I'm going to try and do things on my own"

Comment: With "on my own", you're focusing on "alone"; in the title of the question "alone" does not appear, so I figured the OP knows what "alone" means and was in the dark with respect to "make it", which might be paraphrased "get out of here alive", i.e. to survive the danger.  *Where's Johnson? --He didn't make it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence means "Perhaps he will manage to survive in a difficult situation. He will try to do it on his own. He considers the ways of getting out of "here".

Answer (score 2):

One of the common [definitions of "Make it"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-it) is to survive or endure hardship.  For example: "Will my son make it through the night doctor?"  or "I've been through worse trials, I'll make it this time." Based on the context given, that is probably what Paul Dano's character meant.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Dano's character wants to get off the island he's marooned on. That's the goal that "make it" refers to.

He says that when he saw Daniel Radcliffe, he "thought he was rescued", but it turns out Radcliffe is "just a dead dude". So that means that Dano has to "make it alone": he has to find his way back to civilization on his own.